# Google Pub/Sub Python Subscriber gets ALREADY_EXISTS after 10 minutes

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub

I deployed a Python subscriber Sunday morning. The subscriber restarts every day. Starting today (3 days later), it experiences an ALREADY_EXISTS error 10-20 minutes after starting.

I've restarted it several times now. Every time it runs fine, retrieves previous messages and processes correctly. Then about 10-20 minutes later it dies again. At the time it dies, it didn't receive any messages and nothing significant happened.

**Subscriber code**

```
project_id = '***'
subscription = 'pop'
subscription_id = 'projects/{}/subscriptions/{}'.format(project_id, subscription)

def subscribe(callback):
    subscriber = pubsub.SubscriberClient()
    subscription = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_id)
    future = subscription.open(callback)
    future.result()
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 54, in error_remapped_callable
return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 341, in _next
raise self
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.ABORTED, The operation was aborted.)>
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "../monitors/bautopops.py", line 45, in <module>
main()
File "../monitors/bautopops.py", line 41, in main
gmail.start_pubsub_subscription(callback)
File "/home/ec2-user/bautopops/gmail.py", line 270, in start_pubsub_subscription
pubsub.subscribe(pubsub_callback)
File "/home/ec2-user/bautopops/pubsub.py", line 19, in subscribe
future.result()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/futures.py", line 103, in result
raise err
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_consumer.py", line 336, in _blocking_consume
for response in responses:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_consumer.py", line 462, in _pausable_iterator
yield next(iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 347, in __next__
return self._next()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 56, in error_remapped_callable
six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.Aborted: 409 The operation was aborted.
Guest worker-005 exited with error A process has ended with a probable error condition: process ended with exit code 1.
```

I found in the [Google Pub/Sub Reference](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/error-codes) that error 409 means ALREADY_EXISTS:

> The topic or subscription already exists. This is an error on creation operations.

This really doesn't help since I am not creating a subscription. I am only subscribing to one already created, as described in the [Google Cloud Docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/pubsub/subscriber/index.html#pulling-a-subscription).

Lastly, I found this [Github Issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/4792) which experiences the same error, but under totally different circumstances. It does not seem to be related to my problem.

Please help.

Comment: Can you report your issue per instructions at https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers for the support staff to look into your specific project to see if there are more insights internally?